# How to bind data from BitmapData to WPF Image Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapdata

I'm using MVVM and in my ViewModel I've got some BitmapData collections.
I want them to appear in my View as Images through data binding.

How can I do that?

---

Solution:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(BitmapData), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class BitmapDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapData data = (BitmapData)value;
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(
            data.Width, data.Height,
            96, 96,
            PixelFormats.Bgr24,
            null);
        int len = data.Height * data.Stride;
        bmp.WritePixels(new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, data.Width, data.Height), data.Scan0, len, data.Stride, 0, 0);
        return bmp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, thanks to Clemens.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(BitmapData), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class BitmapDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapData data = (BitmapData)value;
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(
            data.Width, data.Height,
            96, 96,
            PixelFormats.Bgr24,
            null);
        int len = data.Height * data.Stride;
        bmp.WritePixels(new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, data.Width, data.Height), data.Scan0, len, data.Stride, 0, 0);
        return bmp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can set [Image.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) from an image file path bears on the existence of an automatic conversion (provided by [ImageSourceConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter.aspx)).

In case you want to bind Image.Source to an object of type [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx) you would have to write a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that could look like below. You would however have to find out about the details of writing a [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) from BitmapData.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class BitmapDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = (System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData)value;
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(data.Width, data.Height, ...);
        bitmap.WritePixels(...);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8127001/1136211) is helpful for implementing the conversion.