# Kinect for Windows and MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, kinect

I would like to display color frame from Kinect for Windows v2 on the WPF window. I want to use MVVM light toolkit.

In tradition way (code behind) I should use:

```
private void InitializeCamera()
{
    if (_kinect == null) return;
    FrameDescription desc = _kinect.ColorFrameSource.FrameDescription;
    _colorReader = _kinect.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();
    _colorPixels = new byte[desc.Width * desc.Height * _bytePerPixel];
    _colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(desc.Width, desc.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
    CameraImage.Source = _colorBitmap;
    _colorReader.FrameArrived += OnColorFrameArrived;
}
```

In XAML I have:

```
<Image x:Name="CameraImage" />
```

So how can I bind data from ViewModel to my view ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind data from BitmapData to WPF Image Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518625/how-to-bind-data-from-bitmapdata-to-wpf-image-control)