# Is there any way to directly map a raw array to an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a simple path tracer I've written that I'd like to be able to show a real(ish)-time preview of in my GUI. Currently, I have this working with some hacky solutions:

App is .NET Core 3 based. GUI is .NET Core 3 WPF. The GUI is its own project, while the actual renderer is a separate class library. Currently, I'm using an Image object in the GUI, with its source bound to Renderer.ImageBuffer, which is a Bitmap. I've added some INotifyPropertyChanged code to let the GUI know that it should refresh with a user-set interval. I'm using this converter to get something displayed there:

```
public class ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is System.Drawing.Bitmap rawBitmap)) return null;
        using var memory = new MemoryStream();
        rawBitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memory.Position = 0;
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();

        return bitmapImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However, when I enable the update code in the renderer, there's a huge amount of overhead converting from the raw bitmap data to the GUI-friendly BitmapImage format, and it slows the render down substantially. As far as I can tell, there's no way to access the BitmapImage object type directly from the backend without making the class library a WPF project itself in Core 3. Is there a better way that I can be doing this, or a more appropriate control for mapping raw values to something viewable in the GUI?

Comment: Why is the source property a System.Drawing.Bitmap? When you ask "*is there any way to directly map a raw array to an image in WPF?*" the answer is: sure, just bind an Image's Source property to a property of type `byte[]`. Built-in type conversion makes it work out of the box.

Comment: Huh, no kidding. Ya learn something new every day. I'll have to give that a try. What format does it expect the byte array to be in for this to work? Just a flat array the size of the total number of pixels in the image?

Comment: What frame rate are you achieving with your current solution? Are you definitely sure it's the rendering that takes the extra time?

Comment: If you're into maximum performance (60fps, eventually more) with minimul CPU usage, you can build a Directx 12 asset that you inject in a WPF viewbox or something, and have for instance a cuda-directx12 interop. You will have an latency below the microsecond.

Comment: @MatthewHeimlich The byte array would contain an encoded image frame, e.g. a PNG or JPEG. Binding a raw pixel buffer would be difficult, unless you know the bitmap width, height and pixel format in advance.

Comment: In a scenario where all bitmaps are equal in size and format, you could write a Binding Converter that converts a raw pixel `byte[]` and which has properties for the width, height and format.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact of life that you will, sometimes, have to "interop" with `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in WPF Applications. You are using a `BitmapImage` because you would like a `BitmapSource`, right? You are in luck! [`WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netframework-4.8) is supported in .NET Core 3.

Your converting in an IValueConverter instance makes this quite tricky. In any case, the idea is to keep only one `WriteableBitmap` around and use `WritePixels` [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127001/copy-a-system-drawing-bitmap-into-a-region-of-writeablebitmap), to copy the data without the overhead of re-creating the bitmap. WPF will update at each rendering pass, so you will definitely get your result. I suggest finding a way to "stuff" the `WriteableBitmap` into your view-model and pass it directly as such, without the converter.

You may (possibly **will**) have to re-create the source occasionally, because I suspect you might want to allow *resizing your application*. Whenever the GUI is resized, you will need to `new` the `WriteableBitmap` with the new size. You will also have to make sure you get the `DPI` setting right, if you are developing a DPI-aware application. Thankfully, the `WriteableBitmap` can manage [some of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Double_System_Double_System_Windows_Media_PixelFormat_System_Windows_Media_Imaging_BitmapPalette_) (note the constructor arguments) for you.

## Update

I ran this code (similar to yours)

```cs
    //Load a bitmap in memory from file. Size is 1896 x 745, 
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"...");

    //Start a stopwatch to measure performance.
    Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    //Perform 500 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;

            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            //testImage is an Image control in the UI.
            testImage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }

    watch.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");

    //Just one test run of this takes about 7000 ms!!!
```

This takes ~7 seconds to run.

Then, I run this code:

```cs
    //Load a bitmap in memory from file. Size is 1896 x 745, 
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"...");

    //Create the BitmapSource (a WriteableBitmap). 96 is the dpi setting.
    WriteableBitmap writeableBMP =
        new WriteableBitmap(1896, 745, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);

    //Start a stopwatch to measure performance.
    Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    //Perform 500 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        //Lock the bits to copy from the bitmap to the image source.
        BitmapData data =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        //Prepare the buffer size (System.Drawing.Bitmap specific)
        int bufferSize = rect.Height * data.Stride;

        //Prepare the write rectangle, of course this is the entire image.
        Int32Rect writeRectangle = new Int32Rect(0, 0, 1896, 745);

        //Write the pixels
        writeableBMP.WritePixels(writeRectangle, data.Scan0, bufferSize, data.Stride, 0, 0);

        //Unlock the bits, to prepare for another cycle.
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        testImage.Source = writeableBMP;   
    }

    watch.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");

    //Multiple test runs of this take ~300 ms!!!
```

This second piece of code, in all its glorious sloppiness, executes in ~300 ms. It copies the entire bitmap **in every step**. A 1896 x 745 bitmap, should be relatively average for a screen UI that is "almost" maximized.

My suggestion to use a `WriteableBitmap` improves the run-time of achieving the same result with the originally posted code by about ~7000/300 > ~20 times in my machine. Would you possibly try this as I have posted it, and let me know if it runs any better for you? Having had exactly the same problem with you (and switching to a `WriteableBitmap` of course), I am hard pressed to believe that it [only improves your running time by 1-2%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885360/is-there-any-way-to-directly-map-a-raw-array-to-an-image-in-wpf/58885570#comment104040265_58885570). You may have to share some more details of your UI rendering code, so that I can try to locate other potential bottlenecks.

Of course some overhead is to be expected by the rest of the WPF rendering pipeline, as I am only measuring a critical part of the code (relatively roughly, no less) but, in general, the `WriteableBitmap` is close to "as good as it gets" before you abandon software rendering in WPF for any other rendering engine (e.g. hardware).

(I have received 1 downvote and 1 vote to delete this answer so far)

Comment: It took a bunch of extra work to make everything nice and thread safe, but I ended up getting your solution to work with only 1-2% difference in render time compared to rendering without the preview. Going to investigate how the byte array method described above works as well.

Comment: Hmmm.. is there a chance that you are updating your GUI manually? How are you refreshing your GUI? Also, what is the resolution of your Image? If you bind the WriteableBitmap directly to the `Source` property of your `Image`, you should easily get a tolerable frame rate, unless you are running this on a very slow system, or you have a very large image.

Comment: @MatthewHeimlich I have updated my answer with some test code. I get more than a 20x improvement. Is it possible that you have some other bottleneck in your code? If you share more details, maybe we can track this down.